# how to create two tables in sqlite database ?m getting error "table not exists"

Tags: android, sqlite

```
package com.example.userdatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String BC_TABLE = "bc";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "supervisor";
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_PASS = "password";
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "USER_DATA";
    private static int DATABASE_VER = 1;
    /*
     * here we create the "create table query" the spaces while writing the
     * query must be used carefully, any miss of the space between the element
     * of the query may give a serious exception/error
     */
    private static final String BC_NAME = "bcName";
    private static final String BC_ID = "bcId";
    public static final String BCC_ID = "bccId";
    private static final String TERMINAL_ID = "terminal";
    private static final String CENSUS_CODE = "census";
    private static final String BRANCH_CODE = "branch";
    private static final String MOBILE_NO = "mobile";
    private static final String ADHAAR_NO = "adhaar";
    private static final String ACCOUNT_NO = "account";
    private static final String BANK_RO = "bankRo";
    private static final String PIN_CODE = "pinCode";
    private static final String IFSC_CODE = "ifscCode";
    private static final String BC_SUPERVISOR="connectiion";

    private String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_NAME
            + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY , " + COL_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL " + ");";
    ***
/*Second table create query*/
    private static final String CREATE_BC = "CREATE TABLE " + BC_TABLE + " ("
                + BC_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + BC_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + TERMINAL_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + BCC_ID
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + CENSUS_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + BRANCH_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + MOBILE_NO
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + ADHAAR_NO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + ACCOUNT_NO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + BANK_RO
                + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + PIN_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + IFSC_CODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + BC_SUPERVISOR
                + " FOREIGN KEY (" + BC_SUPERVISOR + ")REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME
                + "(" + COL_NAME + "));";

***

    /*
     * this is the constructor of DatabaseHandler class , having instance of
     * context class as an argument
     */
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        // we implement the super class
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER);
        Log.d("database created", "database ready");

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /*
     * this is the first time the database is written , this method takes object
     * of SQLiteDatabase class as an argument,since execSQl is the method of
     * SQLiteDatabase class,thus to use execSQL we need to instantiate the
     * SQLiteDatabase class
     */
    /* Avoid using getWritable() or getReadable() within onCreate() */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE);
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BC);
        Log.d("table created", "tablecreated");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /* user defined method to insert the record into the table supervisor */
    public void insertRecord(DatabaseHandler dbh, String name, String password)
            throws SQLException {

        SQLiteDatabase sdb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.COL_NAME, name);
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.COL_PASS, password);
        // can also use long id=sdb.insert(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_NAME, null,cv);
        sdb.insert(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("data insertion", "one row inserted");

    }

    /*
     * here we make use of cursor class,make the query to the table to fetch
     * both the columns of the table,and returns the cursor to the hosting
     * activity then the cursor is moved to the whole result set performing
     * various comparisions
     */
    public Cursor checkdata(DatabaseHandler dbh) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = { DatabaseHandler.COL_NAME, DatabaseHandler.COL_PASS };
        Cursor CR = db.query(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        Log.d("data retrieveing", "checkdata");
        return CR;
    }
```

/*here i used insert method to insert data into the table */
        public void insertBcData(DatabaseHandler dbh, String bcId, String name,
                String terminalId, String bccId, String censusCode,
                String branchCode, String mobileNo, String adhaar, String account,
                String bankRo, String pinCode, String ifscCode) throws SQLException {

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.BC_ID, Integer.parseInt(bcId));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.BC_NAME, name);
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.TERMINAL_ID, Integer.parseInt(terminalId));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.BCC_ID, Integer.parseInt(bccId));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.CENSUS_CODE, Integer.parseInt(censusCode));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.BRANCH_CODE, Integer.parseInt(branchCode));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.MOBILE_NO, Integer.parseInt(mobileNo));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.ADHAAR_NO, Integer.parseInt(adhaar));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.ACCOUNT_NO, Integer.parseInt(account));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.BANK_RO, Integer.parseInt(bankRo));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.PIN_CODE, Integer.parseInt(pinCode));
        cv.put(DatabaseHandler.IFSC_CODE, Integer.parseInt(ifscCode));
        long bc = db.insert(DatabaseHandler.BC_TABLE,null, cv);
        Log.d("Bc data", "bc data insertion done");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: If you've added the table later, uninstall your app to recreate your database. Also note that your first table is missing a space between column name and type so the column won't be by the name you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The syntax of the first table CREATE is wrong**, change it to

```
private String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_NAME
            + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY");";
```

also you are inserting null values to primary key

```
sdb.insert(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

Comment: How does dropping a column help removing the syntax problem (missing space)? Anyway this doesn't seem to be OP's problem since he's not reporting about a syntax error but rather "table not found" later on.